# Docker-Machine LS not showing SWARM on manual installation

Tags: docker-machine, consul, docker-swarm

I have successfully created my own Docker Swarm on Digital Ocean machines without using the "docker-machine create" docker SWARM hooks.  My motivation for not using these hooks is to provide better bootstrapping and integration with my Consul provider as well as other things.

The issue I am facing is that "docker -H XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3376 ps" works meaning that my SWARM is correctly initialized but I can't get "docker-compose" to connect since "docker-machine ls" is not recognizing the SWARM.  I have read through the docker-machine code trying to find how "docker-machine ls" recognizes the SWARM but could not find it.  Here is my relevant information

docker-compose-master.yml

```
...

swarm:
    container_name: swarm-agent-master
    hostname: swarm-master-server-1
    image: swarm
    ports:
        - "<MASTER_IP>:3376:2375"
    volumes:
        - "/etc/docker:/certs"
    command: manage -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 --replication --advertise <MASTER_IP>:3376 --tlsverify --tlscacert /certs/ca.pem --tlscert /certs/server.pem --tlskey /certs/server-key.pem consul://consul:8500
    links:
        - consul
    environment:
        SERVICE_NAME: manager
        SERVICE_TAGS: swarm
    restart: "always"

...
```

docker-compose-client.yml

```
...

swarm:
    container_name: swarm-agent
    hostname: swarm-client-1
    image: swarm
    command: join --advertise <AGENT_IP>:2376 consul://consul:8500
    links:
        - consul
    environment:
        SERVICE_NAME: agent
        SERVICE_TAGS: swarm
   restart: "always"

...
```

See the following outputs

```
%> docker-machine ls
NAME                  ACTIVE   DRIVER         STATE     URL                          SWARM
swarm-master-server-1          digitalocean   Running   tcp://<MASTER_IP>:2376       
swarm-client-1                 digitalocean   Running   tcp://<AGENT_IP>:2376

%> eval "$(docker-machine env --swarm swarm-master-server-1)" 
swarm-master-server-1 is not a swarm master

%> eval "$(docker-machine env swarm-master-server-1)" 

%> docker run swarm list consul://<CONSUL_IP>:8500
<AGENT_IP>:2376

%> docker -H tcp://<MASTER_IP>:3376 ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS 
<lists jobs running on AGENT>

%> docker -H tcp://<MASTER_IP>:3376 info
Containers: 3
Images: 4
Role: replica
Primary: <MASTER_IP>:3376
Strategy: spread
Filters: affinity, health, constraint, port, dependency
Nodes: 1
 swarm-client-1: <AGENT_IP>:2376
  └ Containers: 4
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 1
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 514.5 MiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=native-0.2, kernelversion=3.13.0-57-generic, operatingsystem=Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, provider=digitalocean, storagedriver=aufs
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: X GiB
Name: swarm-master-server-1
```

Does anyone know what additional thing I need to do to get Docker Machine to recognize I have a SWARM so that I can connect and use Docker Compose?

ALTERNATIVELY does anyone know how I can point docker compose to the SWARM without docker-machine?

Answer (score 0):

All.  After setting this down and moving on, I managed to figure this out indirectly while solving something else.  To answer my first question, docker-machine creates a config file for each node located at

```
~/.docker/machine/machines/<node_name>/config.json
```

This is where it is getting that information.  I have not tried to edit this directly yet meaning there may be some issues there but that is where it is.

I also realized the answer to my second question.  Docker Machine is merely a convenience for setting the appropriate environment variables under the hood.  More specifically

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://<IP>:<PORT>"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="<path>"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="<name>"
```

Meaning you don't even need it to connect Docker Compose to the Swarm, you just need to set these environment variables.